# How to initialize value within 2 hashmaps

Tags: java

I have a hashmap within another hashmap and I'm trying to access that data, but I'm getting NUllPointerExceptions. My code goes like this:

```
public class A {
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>> B;
    int data;

    public A() {
        B = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        data = 0;
    }
}

public class C {
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, A> D;

    ....
    D = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, A>();
    ....
    D.put(someKey, new A());
    ....
    if(!D.get(index).B.contains(key)) {
        D.get(index).B.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    D.get(index).B.get(key).add(value);
```

I get a NullException on the line `if(!D.get(index).B.contains(key))`. I'm guessing it's because of the `List<String>`. How do I fix this?

Comment: I would suggest to move some of the code from class C(putting object in list of B) and make method in class A, so that you will not have to repeat that code again and again.

Answer (score 0):

In `if(!D.get(index).B.contains(key))` , the NPE is caused by `D.get(index).B`, check if   `D.get(index)` is null.

Comment: If I check for that, I get a NullPointerException on the next line, `D.get(index).B.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());`

Comment: @user3666471 The NPE is thrown while you do the check `if(!D.get(index).B.contains(key)) {`, you should check if D contains index like `if(!D.containsKey(index)){ ... }`

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be with the D.get(index) part of it. If index is not a proper key for D, then it will return null, and then you're trying to perform something with null, which is throwing the error. Consider a try/catch instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
D = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, A>();
D.put(someKey, new A());
A aObj = D.get(index);
if (aObj != null) {
    if (!aObj.B.contains(key)) {
        aObj.B.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    aObj.B.get(key).add(value);
}
```